# Model's property is null when viewing detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined a model, Item, which has the following properties:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

}
```

I am trying to reference the Category from within the detail view on the Item controller. My code in the controller is:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

However, when I explore the item object here I can see the CategoryId is correctly set, the Category property is set to null. Therefore when I reference Item.Category.Name I am getting a blank result. I have tried making my properties virtual (following a tutorial on-line) but this didn't seem to fix the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use EF? otherwise show us your repository code.

Comment: You need to include your Category obejct. db.Items.Include(e => e.Category).Find(id); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348663/c-sharp-entity-framework-how-can-i-combine-a-find-and-include-on-a-model-obje

Comment: is Item class generated by template or you have created it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *lazy-load* the property by marking `Category` as virtual:

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

This will fire *another* query to the data store asking for the related category as soon as you access the `Category` property. `item.Category.Name` for example.

Or you can *eager-load* the category by using the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
Item item = db.Items
              .Include(item => item.Category)
              .FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == id);
```

This will retrieve the item including the related category from the data store in 1 query. Notice I used [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here in stead of [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), since the return type of `Include` is `IQueryable<T>` and not `DbSet<T>`.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info about loading related data.