# EF6 Ignoring related data

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-relationship

Scenario

```
public class Product : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dimension { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
    public bool Featured { get; set; }
    public Farm Farm { get; set; }
    public int FarmId  { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sell Price
    /// </summary>
    public decimal BidPrice { get; set; }
    public int QuantityAvaliable { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}

public class Category : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CategoryImage { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship setup

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Created).HasColumnType("DateTime");
        Property(x => x.Modified).HasColumnType("DateTime");
        Property(x => x.BidPrice).HasColumnType("Decimal");

        #region RELATIONSHIP
        //BelongsTo
        HasRequired(x => x.Farm);
        HasRequired(x => x.Category);

        HasMany(x => x.Images);

        #endregion
    }
```

So I have this two model where I need to bring the data from Product model with Category information

I have checked my database, the data is consistent, the Product record have the FK for the Category record.

but when I try to get Product Data using EF6, the category information  doesnt come, I get a null object.

```
Because of = () =>
    {
        _product = _repository.Find(p => p.Id == 1, p => p.Category);
    };

    It should_not_be_bull = () =>
        _product.Category.ShouldNotBeNull();
```

the response from data base is for Category is null. but the record is there.

I had it working properly before. for some random magic reason it just stop working.

THE FIND method

```
public virtual TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = CreateIncludedSet(includes);

        return (predicate == null) ?
               set.FirstOrDefault() :
               set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

the CreateIncludeSet

```
private IDbSet<TEntity> CreateIncludedSet(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes)
    {
        var set = CreateSet();

        if (includes != null)
        {
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                set.Include(include);
            }
        }

        return set;
    }
```

the CreateSet method

```
private IDbSet<TEntity> CreateSet()
    {
        return Context.CreateSet<TEntity>();
    }
```

MY DbContext implementation is here

https://github.com/RobsonKarls/FreedomWebApi/blob/dev/Source/Freedom.Infrastructure.DataAccess/Factories/FreedomDbContext.cs

all project is there too for further analisys

any help is valuable.

Thank you

Comment: [code]public virtual TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes) [/code]
 The Method take 2 parameters, first is for Where () and Second one is for Include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is in this line in *CreateIncludedSet* method:

```
set.Include(include);
```

Yes, you include the data but you *do not change you set*. You should change it to something like:

```
set = set.Include(include);
```

Comment: set variable is type of IDbSet and set.Include() returns a IQueryable, I tried to  do this `set.Expression = set.Include(include)`  but Expression has no setter. but i got your point and totally agree with that.

Comment: I got your insight and could solve the problem, I changed Method:
`private IQueryable<TEntity> CreateIncludedSet(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> set = CreateSet();

            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (var include in includes)
                {
                   set = set.Include(include);
                }
            }
            return set;
        }`

Before it used to return a IDbSet and now it Returns a Iqueryable<T>, this way I could do what you told me before.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear, but try something like this....

```
_product = _repository.Include(p => p.Category).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

also see...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348694/6200410

Comment: exactly, p.Category is parameter for Include()