# C# EntityFramework .NETCore 2.0 Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, .net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

.. Hello I know there's been already plenty of questions on this, but still can't get it right no matter what.
I need a many-to-many with custom join table, but every time I try to fetch collection it's still empty.

First class:

```
public class Test1 {

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestToTest> others { get; set; }

    public Test1() {
        others = new HashSet<TestToTest>();
    }
}
```

Second one:

```
public class Test2 {

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestToTest> others { get; set; }

    public Test2() {
        others = new HashSet<TestToTest>();
    }

}
```

And the join table:

```
public class TestToTest {

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Test1")]
    public int test1Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Test2")]
    public int test2Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Test1 test1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Test2 test2 { get; set; }

}
```

But still when I try to get one of them with query like:

```
var cont = new MyContext(); //DbContext
Test1 t1 = cont.test1.Find(1); // Fetches first class ok
var tt = t1.others; // Empty array
```

I really have no idea what more I'm missing there in other to make it work.
If I add a new one to context then it's ok... as long as it's cached -> and it does write row into db. But after restart (without any cache in context), field 'others' is always empty.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not loading as child relationship are setup for `Eager Loading`. `Eager loading` is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query, so that we don't need to execute a separate query for related entities. Eager loading is achieved using the Include() method. So if the relationship entity is not loaded using include then it would **NOT** be loaded.

Change the code as

```
Test1 t1 = cont.test1.Include(t => t.others).SingleOrDefault(t => t.id == 1);
```

You can read about `Eager Loading` at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) Microsoft document.

Comment: Hmm, it actually cannot be compiled and run.
It does say, that 'Cannot resolve symbol Find', which is, that this method does not exists in what Include does return?
Might be a problem, that it's not base c# entity framework, but Pomelo's for MySQL... I'll look into this.

Comment: Thank a lot... Found it. :)

It has to be as:
 "SingleOrDefault(t => t.id == 1);" Instead of "Find"

Found from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348663/c-sharp-entity-framework-how-can-i-combine-a-find-and-include-on-a-model-obje